# C++ Sieve of Eratosthenes error - need help fixing syntax

Tags: c++, syntax-error

I am more from a java/php background and I am now learning C++. I have tried to recreate the Sieve of Eratosthenes in C++ and print out all primes under 5000.

I am writing and compiling this code with http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp_online.php

Please see the code and error message:

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool sieve[](int max)
{
    bool primes[max];

    primes[0] = false;
    primes[1] = false;

    for(int a = 2; a < max; a++)
    {
        primes[a] = true;
    }

    for(int i = 2; i < max; i++)
    {
        if(primes[i])
        {
            for(int j = 2*i; j < max; j+=i)
            {
                bool primes[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    return primes;
}

int main()
{
    bool[] primes = sieve(5000);

    for(int i = 2; i < primes.size; i++)
    {
        if(primes[i])
        {
            cout << i << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Error Message:

```
$g++ main.cpp -o demo -lm -pthread -lgmpxx -lgmp -lreadline 2>&1
main.cpp:5:5: error: expected unqualified-id before '[' token
bool[] sieve(int max)
^
```

Comment: Don't use arrays, use `std::vector` instead. Your particular error message stems from the fact that arrays cannot be assigned or returned from functions, but there are many other pitfalls. Just don't use arrays.

Comment: You get a silver star for implementing the actual sieve algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `vector`, arrays don't work very well in C++. In particular with an array you cannot

- pass it to a function
- return it from a function
- assign one array to another

Here's the code using vectors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;


vector<bool> sieve(int max)
{
    vector<bool> primes(max);

    primes[0] = false;
    primes[1] = false;

    for(int a = 2; a < max; a++)
    {
        primes[a] = true;
    }

    for(int i = 2; i < max; i++)
    {
        if(primes[i])
        {
            for(int j = 2*i; j < max; j+=i)
            {
                primes[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    return primes;
}

int main()
{
    vector<bool> primes = sieve(5000);

    for(int i = 2; i < primes.size(); i++)
    {
        if(primes[i])
        {
            cout << i << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: $g++ main.cpp -o demo -lm -pthread -lgmpxx -lgmp -lreadline 2>&1
main.cpp: In function 'std::vector<bool> sieve(int)':
main.cpp:22:42: error: variable-sized object 'primes' may not be initialized
vector<bool> primes[j] = false;
^
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:38:13: error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope
cout << i << endl;
^
main.cpp:38:26: error: 'endl' was not declared in this scope
cout << i << endl;
^

Comment: I changed "bool primes[j] = false;" to vector<bool> primes[j] = false;

Comment: Could you explain this last error:

main.cpp:38:13: error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope
cout << i << endl;
^
main.cpp:38:26: error: 'endl' was not declared in this scope
cout << i << endl;

Something to do with changing the namespace?

Comment: Yes, cout is defined in the std namespace, so you can just say `std::cout` or you can add `using std::cout;` to the start of your code (as above), or you can say `using namespace std;` to get the whole of the namespace in your code.

Comment: @AndrewB vector <bool> is not an STL container and it doesn't really hold bools

Answer (score 2):

`bool sieve[](int max)` this is not valid syntax to declare a function to return an array. Actually C++ can't return an array from a function.

As you are returning a set of `bool` type, I won't suggest you `std::vector<bool>`, try `std::deque<bool>`

```
std::deque<bool> sieve(int max)
{
    std::deque<bool> d;
    // do something to d.
    return d;
}
```

Comment: There's simply no reason to use a more complex data structure (deque) when a simpler one would suffice. A vector is simply a perfect fit here.

Comment: quote from Effective STL `As an STL container, there are really only two things wrong with vector<bool>. First, it's not an STL container. Second, it doesn't hold bools. Other than that, there's not much to object to.`

Comment: fine, use boost::shared_array if you insist on having a standard-iterable range of booleans. No matter though, in context, this kind of table is almost always used for direct lookup (given an int n, read primes[n]) so vector<bool> not being a standard container is somewhat of a non-issue. vector<bool> is also 8 times more memory-efficient

Comment: I have a simple question: how is d returned by sieve()? Is it going to be copied?

Comment: @jimifiki RVO, copy should be elided

Comment: If the compiler successfully implements Return Value Optimization (RVO) a statement such as `std::deque<bool> primes = sieve(1000);` will perform no copying, the compiled code would pass a reference to `primes` into the function and operate on it directly.